# GTK-doc not rendering a documentation comment for a struct

Tags: c, documentation-generation

I have the following code in a .h file:

```
/**
 * udp_result_s:
 * @available: indicates the availability of the property stored in @data
 * @data: the property value (will only be meaningful if @available indicates its presence)
 * 
 * A transparent struct, representing the result of a query on a UDP object. Note that the @data field will contain unspecified junk *unless* @available is `udp_PRESENT`.
 */
typedef struct udp_result_s
{
  /*< public > */
  udp_availability available;
  void *data;
} udp_result_s;
```

For some reason I completely fail to understand, this is not showing up in the documentation generated by GTK-doc. Everything else that is supposed to be generated from this file *is* - am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
typedef struct
{
  /*< public > */
  udp_availability available;
  void *data;
} udp_result_s;
```

Comment: Even if this works, I would not use this. Changing the code for the sake of documentation seems wrong.

Comment: It's not just "code" and "documentation". It is "*GTK* code" and "GTK-doc". In fact according to GTK conventions, you should declare the struct as `typedef struct _udp_result_s` (note the leading underscore).

Comment: If this is so, then please add it to your answer, because as of now, it just seems like a bad advice.

Comment: I'll update the answer but I have no means to verify that the answer is correct right now(although I'm positive that that is the solution). Please try and let me know if this advice solves your problem. If it does not, it may be helpful if you check GTK-doc logs if they contain anything related.

Comment: @simurg Neither of these suggestions have had any effect at all - it still doesn't show up for some reason.

Comment: Two questions: 1) What do the logs say? Could you find the chance to check? 2) Are there other structs in your code? Are they defined similarly and no problem?

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you separate the struct definition and typedef, like:

```
/**
 * udp_result_s:
 * @available: indicates the availability of the property stored in @data
 * @data: the property value (will only be meaningful if @available indicates its presence)
 * 
* A transparent struct, representing the result of a query on a UDP object. Note that the @data field will contain unspecified junk *unless* @available is `udp_PRESENT`.
 */
struct udp_result_s
{
  udp_availability available;
  void *data;
};
typedef struct udp_result_s udp_result_s;
```